# Python freezes when configuring IDLE

Tags: python, themes, freeze, python-idle

So, recently I  was using the Python theme function for the IDLE program itself. I downloaded three themes and built my own one, which is selected now. The problem is, I forgot to set colours for the blinker and highlighting, which is hugely problematic. When I went to see if I could change back to the default setting, Python IDLE simply froze up when I selected 'Configure IDLE' under options. I can still scroll through the file, attempt to close the window and minimise it etc, but it has just frozen up. I can't close it or continue working with the file. I've removed Python and then reinstalled it but that hasn't worked, should I just manually delete the themes and force IDLE to use the original one, or is there a way to fix this?

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'Python theme function'.  But anyway... What I understand is that you hand edited $HOME/.idlerc/config-highlight.cfb, but omitted some of the needed entries, in particular, 'hilite' (selcted) background and foreground and cursor foreground.  The result was IDLE freezing when you tried to open the Preferences dialog (which never opened properly.  Correct?  I am asking for details so I can attempt to make IDLE more robust when given bad input.  I am slightly surprised that IDLE opened and only froze at this point.

Comment: In IDLE you can customise colour schemes, sorry, it's not a massive thing. If you go to (Options > Configure IDLE > Highlighting) you can customise different colours, eg what colour text is if it's an error, or what colour Python keywords are.

Comment: I am quite aware of this, having recently patched that part of the code.  It copies a complete existing theme under a new name, lets you selectively alter colors, and then saves the new complete theme.  Not changing something should not be a problem.  If you managed to do something on the Highlighting tab that resulted in IDLE freezing, I would like to know the details, so I can try to prevent the freeze.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy There must have been some issue around what I did manually in the config-highlight.cfg file, as Python, as I said, would freeze. I'm not sure what caused it to freeze, though in hindsight it's safer to use the inbuilt customisation function rather than manually typing up the colours and all. I only did that because I thought the inbuilt function left out a lot of options.

Comment: I did some experiments running 3.5.1 with `python -m idlelib` in the console.  Missing `item = value` results in multiple warnings printed to the console with the default replacement given. A blank value `item =` did not get a warning but resulting in IDLE using a mixture of default and custom color schemes.  The option dialog worked.  A bad value `cursor-foreground = jslfjlskjlksfj` resulted in the same mixed scheme and trying to open Preferences resulting in the freeze you described, requiring Task Manager to close.  A _tkinter.TclError was printed to the console.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy that was the main reason I wanted to change my theme: the cursor colour was the same as the background. Maybe it was this or the fact it was subtly faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one way is manually deleting the faulty theme. This allows the Configure IDLE menu to open. Whoops.

Comment: Revert by hand the bad hand edit is currently the only way to proceed.