# idle crashing when I press configure idle

Tags: python, crash, themes, python-idle

If I go on cmd and write `python -m idlelib`, that would open IDLE. If I were to then go on configure IDLE, on the cmd, it gives be an error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\editor.py", line 574, in config_dialog
    configdialog.ConfigDialog(self.top,'Settings')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\configdialog.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\configdialog.py", line 113, in create_widgets
    self.highpage = HighPage(note)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\configdialog.py", line 693, in __init__
    self.load_theme_cfg()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\configdialog.py", line 998, in load_theme_cfg
    self.paint_theme_sample()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\configdialog.py", line 1279, in paint_theme_sample
    self.highlight_sample.tag_config(element, **colors)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3854, in tag_configure
    return self._configure(('tag', 'configure', tagName), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1627, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid color name "#00224"
```

I probably have a custom theme with an invalid color, however, how am I supposed to delete it if I can't access it (since it crashes when I do so).
There was a post, [Python freezes when configuring IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397377/python-freezes-when-configuring-idle) that had I believe the same issue, but all he says as a solution is "manually deleting the faulty theme", which he doesn't explain. Pretty much, I want to access configure IDLE option without it crashing. Once it does crash, the only way I can close it then is by using task manager or restarting my computer.
As solution, you can tell me how to delete a custom theme without using IDLE if that's possible.

Comment: It does look like an invalid color. It needs six hex digits and you only have 5. If this is preventing idle from opening, you'll have to use some other tool to fix it. Notepad, vi, textedit, something like that.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to access that invalid color using lets say notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is in a custom theme, then the user configuration file you need to edit is `$HOME/.idlerc/config-highlight.cfg`.  In your case, $HOME, based on the url below, appears to be `C:/Users/chess`.  Just add a digit to make six.  You can use the IDLE editor to do so.  You should then be able to edit the color properly in the config dialog.

The problem might possibly be a character missing from the defaults file supplied with IDLE:
`C:\Users\chess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\idlelib\config-highlight.def`

Thank you for opening IDLE in a console, getting the traceback, and posting *all* of it.  It gave me an idea of how to prevent the crash, so I opened a [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue41432)